# egrep ignores empty spaces when searching file contents

Tags: grep, find, php

This is my syntax:

`egrep -lir --include="*.php" '<? ' > ./wrongtag.txt`

and I'm using it directly from the console / terminal (no scripts).

A bit of fluff - the entire server with about 200 websites was migrated from cPanel to Plesk. Shorthand opening PHP tag is not activated / supported on the new server, and is causing occassional errors on various websites. I thought I'd might be able to solve the problem by dumping the search results to a file, but the command ignored the empty space after `<?`, and returned every single *.php file (which I don't need).

How can I use `egrep` to return all *.php files with `<?`  in them?

Comment: What results are you getting then? I don't think the space is the problem.

Comment: @terdon Sorry for the delayed reponse - I was getting all of the *.php files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the regular expression `<?`  with `egrep` which uses extended regular expressions (ERE). In EREs, the `?` means "1 or 0 occurrences of the preceeding character", so your regex means: "find zero or one `<` followed by a space". In other words, find all spaces, including those that come after a `<`. In order to use a literal `?`, you need to escape it (`grep -E '<\? '`).

Alternatively, don't use `egrep` (`egrep` is deprecated anyway, use `grep -E`) here since there's no extended regex feature that you actually want to use. So, try this:

```
grep -lr --include="*.php" '<? ' > ./wrongtag.txt
```

I also removed the `-i` since there's no letters in your pattern, and therefore nothing that can be lower or upper case.

Finally, if what you want to do is remove these tags from all php files, you could simply do it in one step with sed and find:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i.bak 's/<? //' {} +
```

That will make a backup copy of each file (`foo.php` will become `foo.php.bak`) and remove the tag from the original. If, as is likely the case, you just want to remove the whole line that has that tag (I believe php expects the tag to be the only thing on the line, right?), you can delete all lines that have nothing but that:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i.bak '/^ *<? *$/d' {} +
```

Comment: The ERE feature in use was exactly the question mark. It's not special in BRE, but if you escape it in a BRE on a GNU system, it gets the special meaning back. So the two options that work, are `grep '<? '` and `grep -E '<\? '`

Comment: @ilkkachu huh. I thought the `?` was universal. Thanks!

Comment: I have made some adjustments in the answer, please let me know if I've done wrong

Comment: @Quasímodo not at all, thank you!